# Estimating MySQL Query Runtime

Tags: mysql

I ran a MySQL query from command line using the following:

```
nohup mysql --user=root --password=XXXXXXXXX database < report.sql > results.tab
```

This query is extensive (5000 lines) and running a complex search over 90,000,000 rows from 150 tables.

This query has been running for over 24 hours and has not yet finished.

Is there a way I can run status check on this running query?

Comment: Just to confirm, do you really mean ONE query that is 5k lines long and uses 150 tables, or one script that is 5k lines long, executing many different queries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `show processlist` in mysql if that works.

Comment: That command shows only that it is running. Sending data for 79274 seconds. I am trying to get a feel for how long left the query will have until it is complete.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to find time leftout although you can see performance of a query by using explain.